# Cant install libv8 in Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2

Every time I try to install libv8:

```
sudo gem install libv8
```

It just hangs forever.
Any help?

```
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/css_parser-1.2.6.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-09-08 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/sass-rails-3.2.5.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-03-19 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/carrierwave-0.6.2.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7f47f2645870> 1.1.4"]
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a previous version of libv8. The last one didnt work for some reason.

Comment: which one? I think it installs sometimes and sometimes not

Comment: I installed 3.10.8. There are some newer versions now, maybe they could work better.

Comment: I did not change version and it worked, maybe installation needs a time and a steady connection.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it just "hangs forever"? How long have you let it run? Compiling libv8 can take quite a while. On an AWS instance with your source code on an EBS store, I wouldn't be surprised if it takes over an hour.